# Does anybody know the name of this piece?

Tags: theory

Does anybody know the name of this piece?

Comment: Questions like this don’t be answered here: it belongs to the SE music fan site. But if you consider the chromatic dotted eighth notes and  youhave some idea like *Mozart* - google this composer and *adagio* and look up pictures and you’ll find: https://www.google.com/search?q=mozart+adagio+B+dur&safe=active&rlz=1C9BKJA_enCH812CH813&hl=de&prmd=vin&sxsrf=ALeKk01tcu8V_MVIt_uUn--h61V9Xkpcjw:1598941581562&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwip3vDHqcfrAhVI3qQKHVFfAdMQ_AUoAnoECAwQAg&biw=1024&bih=653#imgrc=Gzwoi-44JlD63M

Answer (score 2):

This is the second movement of Mozart's Sonata in F Major, KV 332.

- You can listen to just the Adagio [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HS7nD38ekaU) (YouTube)
- Or the entire Sonata [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAGrJv2VMuM) (YouTube)
- You can view the score [here](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/1/1c/IMSLP56438-PMLP01848-Mozart_Werke_Breitkopf_Serie_20_KV332.pdf) (IMSLP)
- Or Mozart's hand-written copy (partial) [here](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/5/59/IMSLP559838-PMLP1848-Mozart_-_Clavier_Sonata_in_F_Major,_K.332_-autograph-.pdf) (IMSLP)